# ERROR in ./node_modules/codemirror/dist/index.cjs Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Tags: node-modules, codemirror

> ERROR in ./node_modules/codemirror/dist/index.cjs Module build failed:
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\New
> folder\ce\ce\node_modules\codemirror\dist\index.cjs'

It gave me this error while I was trying to use codemirror in my project. so how can I fix this error.

I have tried deleting the node module folder and then reinstalling npm, but it didn't work. can someone help me solve this error. Thank you in advance.